# Google Maps with several different colorful styles on one map

Tags: dictionary

I want to have Google Maps with several different colorful styles on one map like on 
http://demo.mageeklab.com/mgl_colorful_maps/ 
have a look at the controls (top right)
  another example: http://dauten.server29.vorschauseite.eu/YANDEX.html 
  I want to add two styles.
  style 1 (night):

```
var styles = [
{
        stylers: [
        { hue: '#ff1a00' },
        { invert_lightness: true },
        { saturation: -100  },
        { lightness: 32 },
        { gamma: 0.47 }
        ]
},{
    featureType: 'water',
    elementType: 'geometry',
    stylers: [
        { color: '#2D333C' }
    ]
}
];
map.setOptions({styles: styles});
```

and style 2 (dark):

```
var styles = [
{
    "featureType": "all",
    "elementType": "all",
    "stylers": [
        {
            "invert_lightness": true
        },
        {
            "saturation": -80
        },
        {
            "lightness": 30
        },
        {
            "gamma": 0.5
        },
        {
            "hue": "#3d433a"
        }
    ]
}
```

];
    map.setOptions({styles: styles});

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

To link your custom styles to the Map Controls you can create a StyledMapType and pass that into the

So assuming you have your styles in variables like this:

```
var darkStyle = [ ..... ];
var liteStyle = [ ..... ];
```

then you create a **StyledMapType** object:

```
var darkStyledMap = new google.maps.StyledMapType(darkStyle, {name: "Dark Map"});
var liteStyledMap = new google.maps.StyledMapType(liteStyle, {name: "Lite Map"});
```

When you configure your **mapTypeControlOptions** to include the new layers

```
var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 11,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(55.6468, 37.581),
    mapTypeControlOptions: {
        mapTypeIds: [google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, 'Dark Style', 'Lite Style']
    }
};
```

and then pass this into the map as an

```
map.mapTypes.set('Dark Style', darkStyledMap);
map.mapTypes.set('Lite Style', liteStyledMap);
```

If you wan't to set the default style of your map then you can call **setMapTypeId**

```
map.setMapTypeId('Dark Style');
```

An full copy and paste example of this can be found on the Google Maps Javascript API documentation:   [Creating a StyledMapType](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling#creating_a_styledmaptype)